# Erro PHP Artisan Migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tendo o seguinte erro ao executar o comando.

> In Connection.php line 647:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'localhost' (SQL: select *
>   from information_schema.tables where table_schem   a = localhost and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 68:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'localhost'

Comment: Você já modificou a arquivo `.env`? Porque ele está dizendo que o banco de dados chamado `localhost` é desconhecido

Answer (score 1):

Seu arqui de configuração `.env` está configurado de maneira incorreta, no parâmetro onde deveria estar o nome do seu banco de dados, está configurado como `localhost` seu arquivo na parte da configuração dos parâmetros do banco de dados deve ficar assim:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= nome_base*
DB_USERNAME= root(ou seu user local)*
DB_PASSWORD= senha*
```